# How to resolve this weird dependency in maven?

Tags: maven

Have 3 projects. B depends on A, C depends on A and B.  Both A and B depend on a package  P of version 1, namely P1. Now C introduce another versoin of P, name it P2.

The denpendency tree may looks like

```
  P1   P1
  ^     ^
  |     |
  A  <- B
  ^     ^
   \   /
    \ /
     C -> P2
```

To avoid P confilict, I decide to prune P1, by modifying the `pom.xml` in A and B. But weird
thing occurs:  when I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in C, I found it still try to resolve the dependency of P1 !

I then carefully checked every project.

```
In A:  Re-check the pom.xml -> NO dependency of P1 , it won't resolve P1 !

In B:  Re-check the pom.xml -> NO dependency of P1 , it won't resolve P1 !

In C:  Re-check the pom.xml -> NO dependency of P1 itself , but it DOES resolve P1!
  |
  | -  Comment out dependency of A:  Resolve P1 !
  |
  | -  Comment out dependency of B:  Resolve P1 !
  |  
  | -  Comment out dependency of both A & B: Won't resolve P1 !

Finally, I make sure that other packages of A , B and C that depend on do not
 depend on  P1(Actually, P1 is a small SDK with limited usage, I'm sure other
 packages won't denpend on it)
```

So Here is the weird thing: 
From the check, it seems either A or B introduces P1, but in A and B respectively, I check 
and conclude that neither will introduce P1.

Anything wrong?

**UPDATE**

I finally figure out what is wrong: see the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this without more details. What's the output of `dependency:tree`?

Comment: Does a build on command line work? mvn clean package?

Comment: Eclipse is a poor IDE with respect to understanding classpaths. Some of the other IDEs, such as e.g. IntelliJ and NetBeans have a better ability to handle different classpaths for e.g. tests vs code, etc. So there is the posibility that your are hitting issues with Eclipse itself and not a Maven issue. I would recommend checking the classpath in one of the other IDEs to verify that you are doing what you think you are doing. I know IntelliJ will give the correct classpath as I use it myself, and I a reliably told that NetBeans does too.

Comment: please make an answer of what you found and how you resolved the issue. Then mark it answered.

Comment: @Dave Newton, thans for your hint and I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out what is wrong:

From `mvn dependency:tree` in C, I found that P1 exists in the sublevel of B.jar. So I went to B and ran `mvn clean install` to update `B.jar`, then went back to C, and now everything is OK.

I think this might be what happens:

Since B is project-depending on P1, so the old file in `B.jar` that records the dependency of B(actually I extracted **B.jar** and found it is called `META-INF/maven/path/to/B/pom.xml`) **DOES NOT** update as the `pom.xml` in `B` does. So when I ran `mvn eclipse: eclipse` in C, it resovles B(C is also project-denpending on B, so it resolve B.jar ), which then resovles P1 by the **dirty pom.xml** in `B.jar`, not the **fresh pom.xml** in `B`). I think this is a poor design and ambiguous-bug-prone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run mvn dependency:tree on project C, you should see where P1 comes from.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Dave Newton , I answeared it.

Comment: This IS an answer, and it solved larmbr's problem. This was the correct first step to the solution to this issue.